# Autocomplete when editing android layouts in Visual Studio with Xamarin

Tags: android-layout, autocomplete, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm currently running a latest Xamarin.Android trial installation with up-to-date Visual Studio 2012.

When opening .axml file in visual studio I can see a visual designer and can use it normally, when I switch to the "Source" tab I can see a perfectly fine layout xml with syntax highlighted and whatnot.

The problem is, that auto-complete can only suggest XML comment and CDATA elements, nothing else.

Is there a way to turn android-aware auto-complete in Visual Studio? I recall Xamarin Studio being able to auto-complete layouts, but when opening a solution, which was edited in Visual Studio, Xamarin Studio also fails to auto-suggest.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Switched to the paid version and the problem still persists in both Xamarin and Visual Studios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can easily add the Intellisense-like feature in visual studio for your android layout.

The step by step tutorial is here https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1920119-how-do-i-enable-intellisense-in-android-axml-files-

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin studio you may simply right-click on axml file and select - "Open with/Source Code Editor"
Unfortunately, i can't check it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Works for me in Xamarin Studio. Made my day!

Answer (score 1):

After so many struggles, the only solution, which worked out for me after all, was to use IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse to edit my android layouts, and writing code-behind in Xamarin Studio. Ditching Xamarin and going back to development with Java worked out even better.

Comment: It's now 2015.. did you found a solution?

Comment: @RageCompex , I don't work with Xamarin anymore. As I said above, I used IDEA to edit my xml layouts as a workaround and it worked out pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

For our project the best solution was to use
- VS to edit cs code
- Android studio to work with styles, layouts,...

How do we work:

- Assume the project located in **C:\projects\fun**
- Create an Android project in **C:\projects\fun\AndroidStudio**
- Using bat script bellow create symlinks to resources folder and AndroidManifest.xml

**script.bat**

```
mklink /J C:\projects\fun\AndroidStudio\app\src\main\res  C:\projects\fun\Resources
mklink /H C:\projects\fun\AndroidStudio\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml C:\projects\fun\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml
```

it doesn't require to use axml instead of xml files, designer works fine, preview too.

Comment: Does intellisense works in custom xml files with this option?

Comment: @Natiq unfortunately I don't use this approach because Project Rider is available. It supports xamaring projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Autocomplete work only on files with .axml extension.
If your file type is xml you can create new file with axml extension and copy the content of the xml old file to the new axml file (sometimes just renaming the file don't work)

Comment: Sorry, not an answer to my question. It says "When opening .axml file in visual studio I can see a visual designer..."